# Datagrid in WPF shows blank rows and columns

Tags: c#, datagrid, datatable, wpf-controls

I have a small datatable in a WPF application. I want to bind it to the DataGrid ,but the datagrid shows blank row.Kindly help

Code : C#

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("aaa");
        dt.Columns.Add("bbb");
        dt.Rows.Add(1, 2);
        dt.Rows.Add(3, 4);
        int i = dt.Columns.Count;
        int rows = dt.Rows.Count;
        dataGrid1.CanUserAddRows = false;
        dataGrid1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
    }
```

Code : XAML

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="136,108,0,0" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the `AutoGenerateColumns="true"` and check.

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="true" Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="136,108,0,0" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
```

Comment: Found that and worked fine. I dont know why is it false by default. Thanks you anyways

Comment: It's false because most of us prefer explicit column configuration.